# Writing array into csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sql-server, ruby, csv

I want script save results into .csv or .txt file. My script must perform select into mssql database and send all strings from this request on email.
My code:

```
require 'tiny_tds'
require 'csv'

@db_host  = 'myserver.com'
@db_user  = 'mylogin'
@db_pass  = 'mypassword'
client = TinyTds::Client.new(:host => @db_host, :username => @db_user, :password => @db_pass)
results = client.execute("    SELECT * FROM mydatabase    ")

results.each do |row|
p $rows = row.to_a

p h = $rows
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") {|csv| h.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem} }
end
```

My problem:

The generated csv file contains only the first line of my request. How can I write to a file all the strings of my request?

Comment: you need to put the results.each loop into the CSV.open block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? CSV creation outside the results loop.

```
require 'tiny_tds'
require 'csv'

db_host  = 'myserver.com'
db_user  = 'mylogin'
db_pass  = 'mypassword'
client = TinyTds::Client.new(:host => db_host, :username => db_user, :password => db_pass)
results = client.execute("SELECT * FROM mydatabase")

CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  results.each do |row|
    csv << row.to_a
  end
end
```

Comment: I get an error when so doing: C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1675:in `<<': undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: I have updated the example with ".to_a" on row, which I suspect might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to already have a matrix inside `results`. So, instead of this:

```
results.each do |row|
  rows = row.to_a
  CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    rows.to_a.each { |elem| csv << elem}
  end
end
```

all you need is to convert a matrix to the array of arrays and feed it to `CSV`:

```
results.map! { |row| row.to_a.map(&:to_a) }
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") { |csv| csv.replace results }
```